# How does Translate inline work

Tags: magento2.3, translate

How does translate inline work? I'm trying to change a previous translation in the checkout "Proceed to checkout" button. ATM all our websites have the same translation of the button but I need to change it for store specific to something else.

When I activate translate inline and find the word I want to change I do check the box for "for this store view only" And I can change it, however when I disable translate Inline it changes back to the original word. Is there a file where all the translates from translate inline save to?

Or do anyone know why I can't change the word?

Comment: Maybe you can view the "Translation" database table.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says :

> Magento 2 Inline Translation is theme specific, if you change the store theme, you need to do it again.

I would say it's a non technical solution to add translation but, the way it should be handled is using i18n

In your magento code you should have a file like this one

`app/design/theme/default/i18n/us_US.csv`

It's on that csv file that you would put all your theme translation

You have one file per language

`app/design/theme/default/i18n/fr_FR.csv`

```
"Hi","Salut"
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for the replay. 

I do have one nb_NO.csv under app/design/smartwave/porto_child_i18n. I can see some translation there that has been done in the past.

However, i also have a translation (no_NO).csv file under vendor/magento2translation/lanuage_no_no. Seems to me that most of the translation is done in this file. I tried last night to add a translation there that i can't see in translation DB or in nb_NO.csv in theme folder. But no luck. Do you have any idea why translation is not working?

Comment: Either the translation isn't in the file; either the text isn't asked to be translated in frontside. Make sure you clean your cache and re-deploy the static from the language after doing your translation. If it's still not working I don't have more ideas :/